# Could i run Android Studio on windows 7 with AMD processor?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, intel, amd-processor

i have a notebook with AMD E2 series processor. I confused cz some people said i can't run Android Studio on it with Windows (and they said i have to use intel).
What is the truth actually?
Could i run it on my notebook?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Here are the system requirements: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

Comment: How difficult is it to *try*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were probably referring to the lack of Intel Virtualization Technology which helps boost Android VM performance greatly. If I'm not mistaken, AMD has a similar technology that should work just as well.

Either way, even without CPU level VM support, you can still use Android Studio as well as VM just fine. I would suggest you debug on an external device though, whatever the case may be, since your processor's rather slow. The last thing you need is a VM running on top of everything.

Comment: What about the emulator?

Comment: I checked, your processor has AMD-V which is the AMD equivalent VM technology. It'll work just fine. :) Make sure to activate it in your BIOS/UEFI if for whatever reason it is disabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D i could do my homework now. Thanks for ur answer

Comment: No problem. If I helped make sure to mark best answer by hitting that little check sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the emulator on Windows with an AMD processor, but it will be very slow. Enabling the virtualization in the BIOS does not make a difference. You can however, use the ARM images. They will be slow, but working.